# How to implement collision detection into my SFML game

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I'm coding a collision detection system for my SFML game, but it doesn't work on the x-axis. My player is always moving through the object. However, the collision works normally on the y-axis.

I've tried to change the collision system so that it would work with the x-axis just like with the y-axis, but after I had done that, my player was unable to move at all.

```
void Player::Update(float time){
    Keyboard();
    if (STATE==climb) if (!onLadder) STATE=stay;
    if (STATE!=climb) dy+=0.000005*time;
    onLadder=false;
    sprite.move(dx,dy);
    Collision(0);
    Collision(1);
}

void Player::Keyboard()
{
    if (key["L"])
    {
        dir=1;
        if (STATE!=duck) dx=-0.1;
        if (STATE==stay) STATE=walk;
    }

    if (key["R"])
    {
        dir=0;
        if (STATE!=duck) dx=0.1;
        if (STATE==stay) STATE=walk;
    }

    if (key["Up"])
    {
        if (onLadder) STATE=climb;
        if (STATE==stay || STATE==walk) { dy=-0.27; STATE=jump;}
        if (STATE==climb) dy=-0.05;
        if (STATE==climb) if (key["L"] || key["R"]) STATE=stay;
    }

    if (key["Down"])
    {
        if (STATE==stay || STATE==walk) { STATE=duck; dx=0;}
            if (STATE==climb) dy=0.05;
    }

        if (!(key["R"] || key["L"]))
    {
        dx=0;
        if (STATE==walk) STATE=stay;
    }

    if (!(key["Up"] || key["Down"]))
    {
        if (STATE==climb) dy=0;
    }

    if (!key["Down"])
    {
        if (STATE==duck) { STATE=stay;}
    }
}

void Player::Collision(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < obj.size();i++){
        if (getRect().intersects(obj[i].rect))
        {
            if (obj[i].name == "solid")
            {
                if (dy > 0 && num == 1)
                    y = obj[i].rect.top; dy=0;STATE=stay;
                if (dy < 0 && num == 1)
                    y = obj[i].rect.top; dy=0;
                if (dx > 0 && num == 0)
                    x = obj[i].rect.left - width;
                if (dx < 0 && num == 0)
                    x = obj[i].rect.left + obj[i].rect.width;
            }
                }
        }
}
```

I expect the player to be able to move until it's colliding an object. Instead, the player is getting stuck in objects on the x-axis. The collision on the y-axis, however,  is okay.

Comment: A fully working example would be useful to understand and help debug the issue, thanks

Comment: @jackw11111 So, you want me to send you the full code?

Comment: If you can put it up on github and send the link through and I will look over it...

Comment: @jackw11111 [Github repo](https://github.com/fgRuslan/LandEngine) I would be very appreciated if you help me.

Comment: ill get back about it...I will try find the bug, its a big repo though

Comment: @jackw11111 Thank you so much for trying to help me :)

Comment: I've made a pull request with changes.

Comment: @jackw11111 I have just checked your changes and I found out that the code you have written works buggy...Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: I would say start with making an example of moving a player with the arrow keys, making it super responsive, look at examples, there is nothing wrong with copying how its done the best. Implement a collision system, you might want to look into how minimum penetration vectors work, or Seperating Axis Theorem for non-uniform obtuse polygon collision, implement gravity and then jumping. Its a long road, but if you build your systems to be rigorous, efficient and extensible, it will make it easier, and will be EXTREMELY good experience in developing efficient systems in C++. Goodluck and have fun!